# Why does Jaqen H’ghar still look like this guy?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end *Game of Throne* season 2, episode 10 *[Valar Morghulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valar_Morghulis)*, we see Jaqen H’ghar changed his face to another. I believe he said something like Jaqen H’ghar is dead. So why is he, at season 5, back to looking like this guy, instead of the other guy?

[image: Valar Morghulis]

Comment: it appears he is simply doing it for aria's benefit, (as well as being already casted and creepy to keep things simple for the audience)

Comment: @Himarm LoL @ simple for the audience. I'm still confused about the whole Daario Naharis situation.

Comment: I would agree that it's for our benefit. It's easy enough to keep track when we see someone change their face within a single scene. But to be able to come back a season later and remember that this guy is still that one guy from before even though it's a different actor is a little harder.

Comment: @Arm0geddon: What about The Mountain having three faces? He's more versatile than any of the Faceless Men! Also at killing!

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark LoL... yeap! But The Mountain is not a noticeable. He generally gets little screen time. Though I do like this last guy the best.

Comment: @Arm0geddon: Say whaaaaat? You can spot The Mountain in King's Landing while standing on the top of The Wall. He's the most noticeable guy in Westeros. You can notice him from Essos!!! :-)

Comment: Who's to say it really is Jaqen?

Comment: @TLP: I think we should start rolling around a theory that all the non-primary characters are in fact Faceless Men (and women) who were hired to kill other Faceless Men (I mean, if a Faceless Man impersonates Amory Lorch, then I can hire another Faceless Man to kill Amory Lorch without knowing that he too is a Faceless Man). So the entire show is a bunch of characters, and many many Faceless Men, Women and Children. And also White Walkers and ice zombies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To give Arya (and the audience) a familiar face that she can relate to. Mostly the audience, as this never happened in the books. Being a Faceless Man, the man who *calls* himself Jaqen can take up any face at all, but having a different face would confuse the TV viewers. Unlike books, TV is very visual so the show runners have to make different decisions when adapting the story. Thomas Wlaschiha's portrayal of Jaqen H'ghar was *very* popular with the fans. Having Arya's trainer be Jaqen H'ghar with his familiar face is a huge draw for the audience, and it ties up the story of Arya nicely.

Comment: And the character was popular for a reason. He's frigging AWESOME!

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark - A man agrees with you. A man is a fan.

Comment: A man is not Jaqen H'ghar, but he is not an inanimate object designed to push air in a way that transforms heat energy to motion, thus cooling it down. In short, a man is not a fan; a man is no one. :-)

Comment: It would actually be AWESOME if it were a different actor in every episode!

Comment: @Arm0geddon You mean like the oracle in Matrix? :)

Comment: It's funny how him keeping the Wlaschiha face makes it harder for Arya to become Noone. He made her give up all her posessions, and yet keeps a face familiar to Arya Stark.